# What is regenerator-runtime npm package used for?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've noticed it in my company's codebase and it has 30M downloads per week so I'm curious about its importance.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

[`regenerator-runtime`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regenerator-runtime) is the runtime support for compiled/transpiled `async` functions. (It may well have other uses, but this is the predominant one.)

When you use a compiler like Babel that compiles modern JavaScript into earlier JavaScript (a process sometimes called *transpiling*), one of the things you can do is compile `async` functions to something that will run on JavaScript engines that don't support `async` functions (such as the increasingly-irrelevant IE11). Babel does the syntax transformation, but the resulting code relies on runtime support from `regenerator-runtime`.

Comment: then why it is not included in babel since it is so important?

Comment: @ezio - Babel doesn't control what `script` files you included in your page/app, that's not its job; it's job is transforming code from A to B. But a bundler (like Webpack or Rollup, etc.) configured to work with Babel will automatically include the runtime support, because that *is* its job.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder excuse my ignorance, new to js ecosystem, but what does runtime support here means?

Comment: @ezio - No need to apologize, there are lots of moving parts here. :-) Including the script in the runtime environment. Babel rewrites `async` function code into code using `regenerator-runtime` (in any code file where an `async` function appears), but `regenerator-runtime` itself only has to be included once, not for every file. So you include it (if you need it) in a `script` tag in the resulting page.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that is the point of manual including of it? Why is that not automated (by the bundler)?

Comment: @PEZO - I think *bundlers* do by and large. But Babel doesn't do it, because that requires a wider view of your codebase.